# linq query to join 3 tables onto one table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a main table called M1 which consists of Ids of three individual tables T1,T2 and T3.

I need to join 3 tables onto M1 using their Ids and display their Names
For this I am using the following query:

```
 var query= (from i in dbContext.M1
             join j in dbContext.T1 on i.Mt1_id  equals j.Mt1_id
             join l in dbContext.T2 on i.Mt2_id equals l.Mt2_id
             join s in dbContext.T3 on i.Mt3_id equals s.Mt3_id
             where i.Mid >= 1
             select new
             {
               a=j.name,
               b=l.name,
               c=s.name
             }).ToArray();
```

I have used this way, but I am getting an error stating that "`Type inference failed in call to Join`"

Could any one please tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: where are a, b and c defined. Are they of same type as i.name, l.name and s.name ? Also I am assuming that the Id using for equals are also of the same type.

Comment: j.name ,l.name and s.name are of same type i.e, string..They are present in tables T1 T2 and T3.I defined a,b,c in the view again for displaying.

Comment: You can assign a=j.name,  b=l.name,  c=s.name through foreach loop on your anon type query.

Comment: Thanks for the solution,I fixed the error.Actually in the tables T1,T2 and T3 i gave type of the  id as Tinyint and in the table M1 i gave it as int(11).Thank god..Saved my day..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check Datatype of columns to avoid "Type inference failed in call to Join" exception